# How to properly call a class method from within another method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor () { /* etc */ }
    myFunc () {
        return myFuncToCall()
    }
    myFuncToCall () { /* etc */ }
}
```

What is the correct way to call `myFuncToCall` from within `myFunc`?

Comment: how you have it looks correct

Comment: `this.myFuncToCall()`?

Comment: Exactly how you did it before the `class` syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the class syntax is just a syntax suger for prototype inheritence. every instance method is on the prototype of MyClass.

```
class MyClass {
     constructor() {

     }
     myFunc(){
       return this.myFuncToCall()
     }

     myFuncToCall(){

     }
   }
```